# get (hold of) the wrong end of the stick

Tags: idioms, american-english, british-english

There is a BE idiom:

> - get (hold of) the wrong end of the stick.

Which means: "to not understand a situation correctly."

I was wondering if it sounds natural to Americans as well.
If no, then I wonder what is the AE equivalent for that.

Comment: I'm Canadian and I'm familiar with the idiom, but it's not that common. I can't think of any more common idiom than that though, but it is common to say, "You've got it backwards" or "You've got it all wrong".

Comment: I'm American, and my opinion is very similar to gotube's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's a commonly used idiom in American English. The idiom "get the short end of the stick" is more common, but it has a totally different meaning.

Here are some (of many) different ways to express the thought:

> You have the wrong idea.
>
> You have it all wrong.
>
> You've got it backwards.
>
> It's not like that.

Comment: How about: - "**You've got it backwards**" or 
- "**You've got it (all / exactly) wrong**" or 
-  "**You've got it ass-backwards**" pr  
- "**You've got it bass-ackwards**" @swmcdonnell? Which one do you think fits better here and why?

Comment: I modified my answer to include more alternatives.